# Map[String,Object] from a DB (or Key Value store) to a Shapeless Extensible Record

Tags: scala, shapeless

Map[String,Object] from a DB (or Key Value store) to a Shapeless Extensible Record

**Example:**

Lets say I have a map

```
val fromDB: Map[String, Any] = Map("name" -> "John", "age" -> 25)
```

Knowing that the field "name" should be a string and the field "age" should be an integer, how would I convert that to a Shapeless Extensible Record as below?

```
val user = ("name" ->> "John") :: ("age"  ->> 25) :: HNil
```

My end goal is to create an object as below that can convert the Map using the function "fromDB" using the fields.

```
object User {

  object name extends FieldOf[String]
  object age extends FieldOf[Int]

  def fromDB(data: Map[String,Any]) = {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

I'm open to other suggestion and ways of doing this as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `TypeCase` extractors to write this pretty cleanly:

```
import shapeless._, syntax.singleton._

val StrCase = TypeCase[String]
val IntCase = TypeCase[Int]

def toUserRecord(m: Map[String, Any]) = for {
   StrCase(name) <- m.get("name")
   IntCase(age)  <- m.get("age")
} yield ("name" ->> name) :: ("age" ->> age) :: HNil
```

Or you could make the casts a little more explicit:

```
import syntax.typeable._

def toUserRecord(m: Map[String, Any]) = for {
  name <- m.get("name").flatMap(_.cast[String])
  age  <- m.get("age").flatMap(_.cast[Int])
} yield ("name" ->> name) :: ("age" ->> age) :: HNil
```

Note that I'm returning an `Option[LongRecordTypeHere]` to keep this type-safe—if the keys don't exist in the map or the values can't be cast to the right type, we'll get a `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have learnt something from your answer which is **awesome!!** The reason I'm drawn to shapeless is the need to cut down on boilerplate code. Do you know how I can use this to reduce boilerplate code? As it stands I'm not sure a shapeless record has an advantage over a normal case class if I need to convert it in this manner. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, at minimum you'll need to supply the field names and types—you could get a little more concise than this (especially if you're willing to write your own macros), but probably not much. The biggest advantage of records over case classes is the ability to add and remove fields in a type-safe way.

Comment: What's the difference between _.cast[String] and _.asInstanceOf[String]?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, `cast[String]` lets you avoid `ClassCastException` by returning in `Option` and [can also (sometimes) recover erased types](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast), so that e.g. `List(1).cast[List[String]]` is `None`.